# Xtext validator - check all elements X for element Y validation

Tags: dsl, xtext

I'm here trying to find out if anyone know how can I, in my grammar, make a validator that checks if my step only uses ingredients I have declared before hand in the 'ingredients+=Ingredient+'
I've tried many things but no success, I don't know how can I get all the Ingredients that are declared inside my validator function.

Ty all for your time.

Here is the relevant part of my grammar.

```
Model:
    recipe+=Recipe*;

...

Ingredient:
    'ingredient' (
        (liquid_name=LIQUID_INGREDIENTS_NAME liquid_measure=LIQUID_TYPES_MEASURE)
        |
        (solid_Name=SOLID_INGREDIENTS_NAME solid_measure=SOLID_TYPES_MEASURE)
        )
        quantity=INT;

Step:
    '['
        action=ACTION_TYPES
        ('ingredient' ((ingredient_StepLiquid=LIQUID_INGREDIENTS_NAME)|(ingredient_StepSolid=SOLID_INGREDIENTS_NAME)) | 'place' place=TM_PLACES | 'utensil' utensil=TM_UTENSILS)
        ('time' minutes=INT ':' seconds=INT ',')?
        ('speed' velocidade=SPEED_TYPES ',')?
        ('temperature' temp=TM_TEMPS 'ºC')?
    ']';

Recipe:
    'recipe' recipeName=STRING '{'
        ingredients+=Ingredient+
        steps+=Step+
    '}';
```

Comment: you should have a look at the concept of (cross) references and scoping (and IQualifiedNameProvider) as you dont share the complete grammar and resoning behind LIQUID_INGREDIENTS_NAME vs SOLID_INGREDIENTS_NAME its hard to tell how a solution could look like.

Comment: of course you can do this with validation as well. the eContainer() method or EcoreUtil2.getContainerOfType will help you to navigate from Step to Recipe. From there you can traverse down into ingredients again

Comment: @ChristianDietrich How can i get it with the eContainer method? can you give me an example?

Comment: public void checkStep(Step step) {Recipe r = (Recipe) step.eContainer(); }

Comment: I think i managed to do it, however, I came on this issue because 'ingredient' ingredient=Ingredient
Doesn't auto complete

Comment: again look at cross references and scoping

Comment: Thanks I got it all working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @Christian Deitrich said

I can use either eContainer, and get my recipe with a cast from my step or via my grammar with the help from cross references.